# How to recombine datasets to make them binary in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have workdir where many datasets (C:/1/Datasets). As example i provide only three of them.

```
d1=structure(list(x = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 5L), class = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

d2=structure(list(x = c(2L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 6L), class = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

d3=structure(list(x = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 6L), class = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

We see that here in each dataset there is a metric variable `x` and a dependent variable `class`, it has 2 categories 1 and 2 . I want to recombine the datasets, that are in the working folder with each other.
For example, we combine dataset `d1` with datasets `d2 and d3`. With such a union, all categories of the variable `class` of dataset `d1` should set 1, and the categories of the variable class of dataset  `d2 and d`3 should become zero
like this

```
x   class   dataset
2   1   d1
3   1   d1
4   1   d1
6   1   d1
5   1   d1
5   1   d1
2   0   d2
6   0   d2
5   0   d2
4   0   d2
8   0   d2
6   0   d2
5   0   d3
3   0   d3
4   0   d3
4   0   d3
9   0   d3
6   0   d3
```

after that, we change the join order. `d2`, combine with `d1 and d3` where all values of the `class` variable of dataset `d2` become 1, and all values of the class variable of datasets `d1 and d3` become zero.

in a similar way, recombine all datasets that are in the working folder.
For example if there are 4 datasets
then it will look something like this

```
1 vs 2-3-4
2 vs 1-3-4
3 vs 1-2-4
4 vs 1-2-3
```

and each time, the  categories `class` variable of the main dataset set as one, and the category of class variable for the attached datasets becomes zero. as  result we have 4 separate datasets. (depends on the number of datasets in the working directory)

How to make such a recombination?
any help is appreciated for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will do it.  Just put the dataset where you want `class=1` first.

```
comb_data <- function(...){
    nms <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
    nms <- sapply(nms, as.character)
    dats <- list(...)
    dats[[1]]$class <- rep(1, nrow(dats[[1]]))
    dats[[1]]$dataset <- nms[1]
    for(i in 2:length(dats)){
        dats[[i]]$class <- rep(0, nrow(dats[[i]]))
        dats[[i]]$dataset <- nms[[i]]
    }
    do.call(rbind, dats)
}

comb_data(d1, d2, d3)
#    x class dataset
# 1  2     1      d1
# 2  3     1      d1
# 3  4     1      d1
# 4  6     1      d1
# 5  5     1      d1
# 6  5     1      d1
# 7  2     0      d2
# 8  6     0      d2
# 9  5     0      d2
# 10 4     0      d2
# 11 8     0      d2
# 12 6     0      d2
# 13 5     0      d3
# 14 3     0      d3
# 15 4     0      d3
# 16 4     0      d3
# 17 9     0      d3
# 18 6     0      d3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using base R. It will use a named list of all the data.frames which you want to combine and the name of the data.frame which you want to evaluate:

```
list2combine = list("d1"=d1, "d2"=d2, "d3"=d3)

combineData <- function(main="d1", list2combine){
  new <- do.call(rbind, list2combine)
  new$dataset <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(new),"[.]"), `[`, 1) 
  rownames(new) <- NULL
  new$class <- ifelse(new$dataset == main, 1, 0)
  return(new)
}
```

To iterate through all the elements in the list I would suggest using lapply which returns a list with all data.frames:

```
result <- lapply(names(list2combine), function(x) { combineData(x, list2combine)})
```